# Convert file to byte in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm beginner Windows phone dev. In my app, i have a file "A.img", that has been encrypt by XOR algorithm, how can i convert that file (A.img) to byte[] array for decrypt. I tried but was not succesed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 public static byte[] ToByteArray(this WriteableBitmap bmp) 
 { 
    // Init buffer 
    int w = bmp.PixelWidth; 
    int h = bmp.PixelHeight;
    int[] p = bmp.Pixels; 
    int len = p.Length; 
    byte[] result = new byte[4 * w * h];     

   // Copy pixels to buffer 

   for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++, j += 4) 
   { 
       int color = p[i]; 
       result[j + 0] = (byte)(color >> 24); // A 
       result[j + 1] = (byte)(color >> 16); // R 
       result[j + 2] = (byte)(color >> 8);  // G 
       result[j + 3] = (byte)(color);       // B 
   } 
   return result; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static byte[] ConvertToBytes(this BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        WriteableBitmap btmMap = new WriteableBitmap
            (bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);

        // write an image into the stream
        Extensions.SaveJpeg(btmMap, ms,
            bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```